# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a TimeSpan

Tags: c#, database, winforms

i am getting this error while inserting this time to the database.

Here is the error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a TimeSpan.

And here is the code:

```
dateContainer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy",
                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

private void StartTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timeContainer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt",
                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
cmd.Parameters.Add("Times", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.DBTime);
cmd.Parameters["Times"].Value = this.timeContainer.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("Dates", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters["Dates"].Value = this.dateContainer.Text;
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: At which line you are getting error?

Comment: int numberOfRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); <-- this is the line where i got an error. And the error is on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can try this:

```
TimeSpan span;
if(TimeSpan.TryParseExact(this.timeContainer.Text, "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out span))
{
   cmd.Parameters["Times"].Value = span;
}
```

Comment: I know that in the database, can't put the sign `:`. But, i want the program show the time separate by sign `:`, not in the directly like what you suggest. So, the time in the program will display 01:00 PM, but in the database will store a time 1300. Is that possible sir? And also my database format for the time and the date is `Date/Time`

Comment: Note that for 1 p.m., `"hhmmss"` will give `"010000"`. To get `"130000"` (for 13:00) instead, use `"HHmmss"`.

Comment: What is "not working"? It throws exception, not expected behavior, ...?

Comment: one of the required parameters is missing. i replace the `cmd.Parameters.Add("Times", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.DBTime); and cmd.Parameters["Times"].Value = this.timeContainer.Text;` with the one that you gave me